# SSE works on the array that the number of the elements is not the multiple of four

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, sse, intrinsics

everyone.

My question is if I have three arrays as following

```
float a[7] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 
              5.0, 6.0, 7.0};
float b[7] = {2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0,
              2.0, 2.0, 2.0};
float c[7] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
              0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
```

And I want to perform element-wise multiply operation as following

```
c[i] = a[i] * b[i], i = 0, 1, ..., 6
```

For the first four element, I can use SSE intrinsics as following

```
__m128* sse_a = (__m128*) &a[0];
__m128* sse_b = (__m128*) &b[0];
__m128* sse_c = (__m128*) &c[0];

*sse_c = _mm_mul_ps(*sse_a, *sse_b);
```

And the content in c will be

```
c[0] = 2.0, c[1] = 4.0, c[2] = 6.0, c[3] = 8.0
c[4] = 0.0, c[5] = 0.0, c[6] = 0.0
```

Remaining three numbers in index 4, 5, and 6, I use following code
to perform element-wise multiply operation

```
sse_a = (__m128*) &a[4];
sse_b = (__m128*) &b[4];
sse_c = (__m128*) &c[4];

float mask[4] = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0};
__m128* sse_mask = (__m128*) &mask[0];

*sse_c = _mm_add_ps( *sse_c, 
    _mm_mul_ps( _mm_mul_ps(*sse_a, *sse_b), *sse_mask ) );
```

And the content in c[4-6] will be

```
c[4] = 10.0, c[5] = 12.0, c[6] = 14.0, which is the expected result.
```

_mm_add_ps() add four floating-point in parallel, and the first, second, and third floating-point number are allocated in index 4, 5, and 6 in array a, b, and c respectively. 
But the fourth floating-point number is not allocated to the arrays. 
To avoid invalid memory access, I multiply on sse_mask to make the fourth number be zero before add the result back to sse_c (array c).

But I'm wondering whether it is safe?

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you specifically want to use SSE instead of AVX (since it's not as widespread as SSE) ?

Comment: Yes, I want to use SSE instead of AVX

Comment: No, it's not safe to store 4B past the end of `c[]`.  Pad your destination if you want, but loading garbage data as floating point can lead to big slowdowns if it happens to represent a denormal value.

Comment: Arrays are stack allocated so the reads are likely safe but the write to `c` is not because you could overwrite something else on the stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have the mathematical operations right but I'm really not sure using casts like you do is the way to go to load and store data in `__m128` vars.

### Loading and storing

To load data from an array to a `__m128` variable, you should use either `__m128 _mm_load_ps (float const* mem_addr)` or `__m128 _mm_loadu_ps (float const* mem_addr)` . Pretty easy to figure what's what here, but a few precisions :

- For operations involving an access or manipulation of memory, you usualy have two functions doing the same thing, for exemple `load` and `loadu` . The first requires your memory to be aligned on a 16-byte boundary, while the `u` version does not have this requirement. If you don't know about memory alignement, use the `u` versions.
- You also have `load_ps` and `load_pd`. The difference : the `s` stands for single as in single precision (good old `float`), the `d` stands for double as in double precision. Of course, you can only puts two doubles per `__m128` variable, but 4 floats.

So loading data from an array is pretty easy, just do : `__m128* sse_a = _mm_loadu_ps(&a[0]);`. Do the same for b, but for c that really depends. If you only want to have the result of the multiplication in it, it's useless to initialize it at 0, load it, then add the result of the multiplication to it then finally get it back.

You should use the pending operation of `load` for storing data which is `void _mm_storeu_ps (float* mem_addr, __m128 a)`. So once the mutliplication is done and the result in `sse_c`, just do `_mm_storeu_ps(&c[0@, sse_c) ;`

### Algorithm

The idea behind using the mask is good but you have something easier : load ans store data from `a[3]` (same for b and c). That way, it will have 4 elements, so there will be no need to use any mask? Yes one operation has already have done on the third element but that will be completely transparent : the `store` operation will just replace the old value with the new one. Since both are equal, that's not a problem.

One alternative is to store 8 elements in your array even if you need only 7. That way you don't have to worry about memory being allocated or not, no need for special logic like above for the cost of 3 floats, which is nothing on all recent computers.

Comment: casting to `(__m128*)` is fine if your data is aligned.  vector types are allowed to alias other types.  `*(__m128*)p` is effectively identical to `_mm_load_ps(p)`, as far as the compiler is concerned.  The load/store intrinsics exist mostly to communicate alignment information to the compiler, and (for FP types) to take care of the type conversion without ugly casts.  For AVX512, the integer load/store intrinsics will take `void*` args, so we can finally drop the ugly `_mm_load_si128((__m128i*)p)` sillyness.

Comment: re: last part: good point that it's not clear if the OP needs to implement `c += a * b`, but I assume so.  Probably all-zeros was just an example.  In that case, the destination is no longer write-only, and the operation isn't idempotent, so the easy solution of using an unaligned vector that ends at the end of the arrays doesn't work.  You could blend with the last aligned vector or something.  It's common to just fall back to scalar, which is fine for the end of a really long loop, but not for processing many different 7-element arrays.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know about the cast, great to know ! I'll stick with intrinsics on my end as I find it clearer that way. I also agree about whether or not the OP implicitly talks about an accumulation or not, so I only adressed what was in the question. Feel free to add an answer about this case.